# Flutter: UI and Codes not updating

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm just a student try to make school project and don't know codding very well. I stuck in somewhere, everything was just fine but then flutter stopped updating my codes in home.dart file. I update my codes change some variables but it does not working, it uses the old code. But other .dart files is working and getting update. I sent the code, I changed AppBar part but its not updating. and I'm getting an error from old code.

```
    class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  List<PopularTourModel> popularTourModels = new List();
  List<CountryModel> country = new List();


  
  @override
  void initState() {
    country = getCountrys();
    popularTourModels = getPopularTours();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if (oldWidget != widget) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Samsun Tur'),
        actions: [
        ],
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 24),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                "BETA",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 28,
                    color: Colors.black54,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 8,
              ),
              Text(
                "Tarihi Mekanlar:",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: Colors.black54,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 16,
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  print('ÇALIŞTI, mı acaba?');
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 240,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: country.length,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index)
                      {
                        return CountryListTile(
                          label: country[index].label,
                          countryName: country[index].countryName,
                          noOfTours: country[index].noOfTours,
                          rating: country[index].rating,
                          imgUrl: country[index].imgUrl,
                        );
                      }),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 8,
              ),
              Text(
                "Size en yakın yerler!",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: Colors.black54,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 16,
              ),
              ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: popularTourModels.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return PopularTours(
                      desc: popularTourModels[index].desc,
                      imgUrl: popularTourModels[index].imgUrl,
                      title: popularTourModels[index].title,
                      price: popularTourModels[index].price,
                      rating: popularTourModels[index].rating,
                      mekan: popularTourModels[index].mekan,
                      desclong: popularTourModels[index].desclong,
                      latitude: popularTourModels[index].latitude,
                      longitude: popularTourModels[index].longitude,
                      distanceToUser: popularTourModels[index].distanceToUser,
                    );
                  })
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("lib/views/home", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.

Make sure your root app widget has provided a way to generate 
this route.
Generators for routes are searched for in the following order:
 1. For the "/" route, the "home" property, if non-null, is used.
 2. Otherwise, the "routes" table is used, if it has an entry for the route.
 3. Otherwise, onGenerateRoute is called. It should return a non-null value for any valid route not handled by "home" and "routes".
 4. Finally if all else fails onUnknownRoute is called.
Unfortunately, onUnknownRoute was not set.
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _WidgetsAppState._onUnknownRoute.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/app.dart:1175:9)
#1      _WidgetsAppState._onUnknownRoute (package:flutter/src/widgets/app.dart:1190:6)
#2      NavigatorState._routeNamed (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:3388:36)
#3      NavigatorState.pushNamed (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:3425:20)
#4      NavigatorState.popAndPushNamed (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:3479:12)
...
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#39fcc
  debugOwner: GestureDetector
  state: possible
  won arena
  finalPosition: Offset(26.9, 51.3)
  finalLocalPosition: Offset(26.9, 27.3)
  button: 1
  sent tap down
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Lost connection to device.
```

Comment: _Lost connection to device._  your device is not connected. And secondly press `ctrl + s` before reloading. And third your code is wrong please fallow your instructor code properly.

Comment: @MRazaImtiaz No I just quit from the device. I changed my operating system, reinstalled android studio several times but the code I changed is never changed. Ctrl+S is not the case I did that millions of time:( And In the Android Studio my code is just fine and it has no errors. I didn't understand what did you mean by 'your code is wrong'. Thank you,

Comment: i had same problem, the ui never updated when saving file. i add GlobalKey to my MaterialApp in main page and it was fixed. please try.